How to name an ad-hoc data type created column in a cte
I have the following cte
with qry as (
    select node_value as 'data()' from (
        SELECT  xml_node.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS node_value
        FROM efactura
        CROSS APPLY efxml.nodes('(/*:Invoice/*:Note)') AS T(xml_node)
        where docid=1241592
    ) q
    FOR XML PATH('')
)

when I intend to get the result in
select * from qry

obviously get the error

No column name was specified for column 1 of 'qry'.

How to name the column?

Most DBMSes support column names in WITH. E.g.
   with qry(mycol) as (
      -- your query returning a single column
   )
   select *
   from qry

will return a data set with a column mycol

Thank you... I didn't know that syntax in cte.

WITH qry AS (
    SELECT node_value AS data
    FROM (
        SELECT xml_node.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS node_value
        FROM efactura
        CROSS APPLY efxml.nodes('(/*:Invoice/*:Note)') AS T(xml_node)
        WHERE docid = 1241592
    ) q
    FOR XML PATH('')
)
SELECT * FROM qry;


Not working, same error
